# Update tableView in two different classes with same model

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

i have two different classes and want to share the same model/database. So if i make a new record to the model/database the tableViews in the different classes should update. Now only the tableView in the same class as insert is updated. Please i need your help. Thanks.

My Code:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtSql

from model import Model

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.initUI()

        self.createNewDatabase()

        self.openEditor()

    def initUI(self):
        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        self.tableView.resize(self.tableView.sizeHint())
        button = QtGui.QPushButton('make Entry', self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.insertEntry)

        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 300, 300)
        self.show()

    def createConnection(self, databasePath):
        # Create a QSQLite database
        self.database = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        # Set path of the database
        self.database.setDatabaseName(databasePath)

        self.database.open()

    def initializeModel(self):
        self.model = Model()
        self.model.setTable("friends")
        self.model.select()

    def createNewDatabase(self):

        databasePath = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save database...', '')[0]
        self.createConnection(databasePath)
        self.createRelationalTables()
        self.initializeModel()

        # Set the model for MainWindow table view
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)

    def createRelationalTables(self):

        sqlQuery = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        sqlQuery.exec_(
                '''
                CREATE TABLE friends(
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                    name TEXT NOT NULL,
                    name2 TEXT NOT NULL)
                '''
        )

    def insertEntry(self):
        # Get number of rows of database
        row = self.model.rowCount()
        # Create an empty record
        record = QtSql.QSqlRecord()
        # Insert record
        self.model.insertRecord(-1, record)

    def openEditor(self):
        # Create an instance of Editor
        self.editor = Editor()
        # Show the editor
        self.editor.show()

class Editor(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.initUI()

        # Set the model for the table view of Editor
        self.model = Model()
        self.model.setTable("friends")
        self.model.select()
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)

    def initUI(self):
        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        self.tableView.resize(self.tableView.sizeHint())

        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 300, 300)
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the Model:

```
from PySide.QtSql import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class Model(QSqlRelationalTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()

    def setData(self, index, value, role = Qt.EditRole):

        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self._items[index.row()] = str(value.toString().toUtf8())
            QObject.emit(self, SIGNAL("dataChanged(const QModelIndex&, const QModelIndex &)"), index, index)
            return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating two models, once in `MainWindow`, and once in `Editor`. You have two instance of the class `Model`, but you are only updating one.

What you want is to create the model only once, and use it in multiple views. The first model and the editor are both instantiated in `MainWindow`, so you just need to pass the model when initializing the editor:

```
def openEditor(self):
      self.editor = Editor(self.model)
      self.editor.show()

class Editor(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, model, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        self.tableView.setModel(model)
```